# Why is http req.url giving two arrays instead of one?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using some code that looks like this since my instructor has forbidden us from using the URL module:

```js
let http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        let request=req.url.split('/');
        
        console.log(request);
    }).listen(5000);
}
```

However, this prints two arrays instead of 1, for the URL

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/translate/e2s/this+is+the+url`

these look like:

```
[ '', 'translate', 'e2s', 'this+is+the+url' ]
[ '', 'favicon.ico' ]
```

I can't index these because they behave as a single array so if I do
`request[3].split('+')`  for instance, I get an error.

Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Comment: You make the request, the browser makes the request for the favicon

Comment: @mplungjan I see, how can I access only the first request then? I tried double indexing like Python but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: You only get ONE request at a time. Ignore the other one